# Is it correct to say "rushed into my ears"?

Tags: grammar, narration

I'm trying to describe the chirping of birds can be heard once I opened the door and my sentence is:

> The chirping of birds that last incessant rushed into my ears when I was opening the old oak door.

Is it correct? Are there any better approaches? (I personally think "rushed into my ears" sounds weird XD)

Thanks.

Comment: It sounds a little weird. Sounds don't rush like self-propelled objects do. The birds rushed. It could be poetic but if that's not the feeling you're looking for, it's more incongruous.